# How to change one value in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem with passing one value from List to datagridview.

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text) <= Convert.ToInt32(label29.Text))
        {
            int a;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(label29.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text); 
            List newList;
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProducts; i++)
            {
                newList = Data[i];
                newList.Amount = a;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = a;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course it's passing value and changing value in all column called "Amount".

How to change only one value, which i want in column "Amount" ?

Comment: i may help you but i am lost in these unnamed variables. how do you handle all these unnamed controls?

Comment: it's a part of code, i can't paste all of my code because it has over 500 lines ;)

Comment: not quite sure what you wan, but perhaps this helps: which column is amount? set `j` to this column number and do not increment it

Comment: I am tried this, but not works. Still it change value in all of rows.

Comment: -> newList.Amount = a; I think it's wrong, because on this line variable Amount in List will have always the value what i set and it will change in every row, right?